# CSS Flexbox Center Items with Positioning

Tags: html, css, flexbox, flexboxgrid

I'm trying to position 3 elements in a specific position with flexbox, all while being centered horizontally and vertically.

Like this:

[image]

This is what I have so far, what am I doing wrong here?

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 800px;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: pink;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: column;

  .first  { 
    background: green; 
    height: 50px;
    align-self: stretch;
  }

  .second { 
    background: blue; 
    height: 100px;
  }

  .third  { 
    background: crimson; 
    height: 100px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="first"></div>
  <div class="second"></div>
  <div class="third"></div>
</div>
```

Have a look at this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/u21uqs7q/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just update your code with following snippet..

```css
.container {
 width: 100%;
 max-width: 800px;
 height: 100vh;
 margin: 0 auto;
 background: pink;
 display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
 
}
 .left  .first { 
  background: green; 
  height: 50px;
 }
 
 .right .second { 
  background: blue; 
  height: 100px;
 }
 
 .right .third  { 
  background: crimson; 
  height: 100px;
 }
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <div class="left">
  <div class="first">111</div>
  </div>
  
 <div class="right">
  <div class="second">222</div>
 <div class="third">333</div>
  </div> 
</div>
```